# How to reshape data in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

I am working on a project where i need to reshape the data in particular Format. I have transformed successfully in Excel but how we can transformed this Data with pandas because in Excel we have the limitation of rows.

```
Territory ID    Patient Id  Doctor Id   Clinic Count    Attribute          Value
43                172        6021          Clinic1      Service Date      06/22/2017 
43                172        6021          Clinic1      Product               A
43                172        6021          Clinic1      Qty                   1
43                172        6021          Clinic1      Amount                80.63
43                172        6021          Clinic1      Age                   1
43                172        6021          Clinic1      Days Last Clinic      0
43                187        5658          Clinic2      Service Date       06/30/2017 
43                187        5658          Clinic2      Product               B
43                187        5658          Clinic2      Qty                   2
43                187        5658          Clinic2      Amount                52.48
43                187        5658          Clinic2      Age                   9y1m
43                187        5658          Clinic2      Days Last Clinic      23
```

This has to be reshape in this format:

```
TerritoryID PatientId   DoctorId    Clinic_Count    Service_Date    Product    Qty    Amount   Age    Days Last Clinic   
    
43            172        6021          Clinic1      06/22/2017       A           1     80.63    1          0
43            187        5658          Clinic2      06/30/2017       B           2     52.48    9y1m       23
```

Comment: Try this `pd.pivot_table(df,index = ['Territory ID', 'Patient Id', 'Doctor Id', 'Clinic Count'], values='Value' , columns=['Attribute'],aggfunc='first').reset_index()`

Comment: @XXavier It is giving syntax error. Can you please try with your own

Comment: Can you post the error here. The code above works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({...}) # Your DataFrame

New_Data = {x:[] for x in list(df.columns)+list(df['Attribute'])}

for x in list(df.columns):
    for j, i in enumerate(list(df[x])):
        if not list(df['Clinic Count'])[j] in New_Data['Clinic Count']:
            New_Data[x].append(i)

New_Data.pop('Attribute')
New_Data.pop('Value')

for x, i in zip(list(df['Attribute']), list(df['Value'])):
    New_Data[x].append(i)
```

Comment: I just share sample data of 2 clinic Count but in reality it is in thousands. So this will not be a good approach of manually giving clinic Count in pd.DataFrame.

Hope this make sense.

Comment: It can do thousands, I just forgot to remove the test ```DataFrame```.

Comment: Can you click the check because it worked?

Comment: There it is getting an error